# USE DATENAME IN SQL SERVER IN STORE PRODECURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure with 3 parametrs
-1 : Start Date
-2 : End Date
-3 : Days Name
the function of this stored procedure is get difference between two date without counting some specefic days

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (@start_date DATE,@end_date DATE,@name_days VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NUMBER_DAYS INT;
;with AllDates AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS DateOf
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,DateOf)
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf<@end_date
)
select SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,dateof) in (@name_days) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as SumOfDays
FROM AllDates;
END
```

my problem is i need to know if i can add in execute procedure two name of days like the example(But this not working with me someone have any suggestion please ! and how to do it)

```
EXEC TEST '2020-07-01','2020-07-13','Monday Tuesday'
```

Comment: You can run that, but it will return no results, because the datename will not match the parameter value.  You would have to change the comparison method.

Comment: `in (@name_days)` isn't going to do what you expect.

Comment: [See also](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a Calendar table, but if you are using SQL 2016+ you can accomplish this using the STRING_SPLIT function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (@start_date DATE,@end_date DATE,@name_days VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @NUMBER_DAYS INT;
;with AllDates AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS DateOf
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,DateOf)
        FROM AllDates
    WHERE DateOf<@end_date
)

select COUNT(*) SumOfDays
FROM AllDates
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@name_days,' ') 
                    WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dateof) = value)

END
```

Comment: (Yes, but not sure how a calendar table would help match/break apart a string like `'Monday Tuesday'`.)

Answer (score 1):

One method to do this would be to use a table type parameter. I also switch from your iterative (and slow) method of use an rCTE to a much faster Tally Table.

Ideally, however, if you want to do this on a much more regular basis, you would be better off with a Calendar Table (Use your favourite search Engine, you'll find 1000's of examples on how to build these) rather than an inline Tally.

Anyway, using a table type parameter, you can do something like this:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.DayNames AS table(DayName varchar(15));
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.TEST @StartDate date, @EndDate Date, @DayNames dbo.DayNames READONLY AS
BEGIN

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) +1)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4), --10,000 days
    Dates AS(
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS Date,
               DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate)) AS DayName
        FROM Tally T)
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOfDays
    FROM Dates D
         JOIN @DayNames DN ON D.DayName = DN.DayName;

END;

GO

DECLARE @DayNames dbo.DayNames;
INSERT INTO @DayNames
VALUES ('Monday'),('Tuesday');

EXEC dbo.TEST '20000101', '20200817', @DayNames;
GO

--Cleanup

DROP PROC dbo.TEST;
DROP TYPE dbo.DayNames;
```

If you don't want to use a table type parameter, you could pass a delimited list in, and then use a string splitter, such as `STRING_SPLIT` (in SQL Server 2016+) or A user built function, such as `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` (Google it).